# Component does not render, but react does not show errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create an application that will sort the array from the smallest to the largest, but at the very beginning I encountered an error. React does not show a single error and the component does not render anyway.

**App.js**

```
import { SortingVizualize } from './SortingVizualize/SortingVizualize';

function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SortingVizualize />
    </div>
  )


}

export default App;
```

**SortingVizualize.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
// import styles from './SortingVizualize.modules.scss';

export class SortingVizualize extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.resetArray();
    }

    resetArray() {
        // I use this method to generate new array and reset
        const array = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            array.push(randomInt(5, 750)); // Min and Max value of number in array
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { array } = this.state;

        return (
            <>
                {array.map((value, idx) => (
                    <div className="array-bar" key={idx}>
                        {value}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </>
        )
    }

}

function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

export default SortingVizualize;
```

Comment: Where are you changing `array` state value? It seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your `state.array` and the `array` in `resetArray` are two different arrays and you never update the one in the state.

You will need to call `setState` to update the state

```
resetArray() {
    // I use this method to generate new array and reset
    const array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        array.push(randomInt(5, 750)); // Min and Max value of number in array
    }
    this.setState({ array });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not triggering any update events since you're using `array.push` to a local variable, which then isn't assigned to the component state. Remember to use `this.setState(...)` to update the array saved in your state, like so:

```
resetArray() {
    // I use this method to generate new array and reset
    const array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        array.push(randomInt(5, 750)); // Min and Max value of number in array
    }

    this.setState({
        array,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your resetArray method you're not assigning your data to your state. Your state's array field still empty then. You may add  `this.setState({ array })` in order to trigger the rerender with generated data.